# Automatic reboot after a BSOD

Tags: windows-7-x64, bsod

How can I make Windows 7 x64 to reboot automatically after a BSOD?
There is a well-known "Automatically restart" option in the system properties -> Advanced -> Startup and recovery, but it seems it affects boot time only. If BSOD occurs after successful boot, the system hangs with a blue screen.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the expected behavior. The automatic restart should apply in all cases, not just during boot. There are some corner cases where it won't work but these are rare and relate to a very specific scenarios. Better proceed this with MS support.